# Fade-In & Out a <tbody> element on <select> change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, onchange

I have a `<select>` drop-down menu which displays different input fields depending on what is selected using JavaScript.

```
<select name="country" onchange="SelectCheck(this);" id="country">
            <option value="United States of America" id="USA">United States of America</option>
            <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
            <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
            <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="Antigua &amp; Barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
            <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
...
</select>
```

The input tags are wrapped in `<tbody>` tags though. I had to do it this way because it's inside of a table and the `<div>` tag does not work.

```
<tbody id="USDLdiv" style="display:none;"> 
        <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="USA License No."></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to add a fade in & fade out effect when you switch between options.

All I got is:

```
$selectoption = $("#country");

$("select", $selectoption).change(function() {
    $("tbody > tr", $selectoption).fadeOut();
});
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Will this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/op2zjb8p/

Comment: is there a single row  , that you are dynamically changing the value of with a fadeIn/fadeOut effect or are there muliple rows in the table which u just wanna show and hide? ! ... if it is the first check this out https://jsfiddle.net/yox5m4r8/ , if it s the second the previous fiddle should work !

Comment: *"it's not working"* is not a proper problem description and is fairly meaningless without some context

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is looking for a `<select>` that is a descendant of `#country` but `#country` is a `<select>` and has no such descendent.

Similarly inside the event handler you are looking for a `<tr>` that is a descendant of the `<select>` and a  has no such descendant

Try:

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    $("tbody > tr").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <select name="country" id="country">
     <option value="usa">United States of America</option>
     <option value="afg">Afghanistan</option>
     <option value="alb">Albania</option>
     <option value="alg">Algeria</option>
 </select>

 <table>
  <tbody> 
         <tr id="usa">
             <td><input type="text" placeholder="USA License No."></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="afg">
             <td><input type="text" placeholder="Afghanistan License No."></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="alb">
             <td><input type="text" placeholder="Albania License No."></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="alg">
             <td><input type="text" placeholder="Algeria License No."></td>
         </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $('tr').hide();
  $(document).on('change','#country', function(){
   var send = $(this).val();
   $('tr').fadeOut();
   $('#'+send).fadeIn();
  });
 });
</script>
</html>
```

Hope it can help you!